# Lumen ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, post, lumen

I am developing a web application using the Framework [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/routing). I looked everywhere, I tried everything but I couldn't find a solution to my problem..

I have a form that I want to validate with jQuery using ajax() with `POST`. I tried to use `csrf_token`, but always without success.

**VIEW** :

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="test" placeholder="Test">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block valide">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS** :

```
$('.valide').click(function () {
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/testAjax',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data : form.serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        // done
    }).fail(function () {
        // fail
    });
});
```

**routes.php** :

```
$app->post('/testAjax', function () {
    return 'I am here';
});
```

Normally I would get the message "I am here", but instead, I get the following error (Please note that if I make the same request using `GET`, it works very well):

`POST http://localhost/testAjax 500 (Internal Server Error)`

How to make an ajax `POST` request using Lumen?

Comment: Can you look at the lumen log file? 500 error can be many many things from configuration errors with the webserver or even exceptions within the application.

Comment: Did you uncomment the middlewares in `bootstrap/app.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply add the following code to the HTML form, allowing the user to be associated to the current form. This is described in the [documentation](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/routing#csrf-protection).

**VIEW** :

```
<form id="form">
    <!-- Added the following line -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="test" placeholder="Test">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block valide">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if someone would not send jQuery POST via form you can simply add to your script code below:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Remember to include this html inside your view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. Please note that the notation `{{ csrf_token() }}` require to use [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

Comment: Sure it is self-build method inside ;)

Answer (score 0):

change the route

```
 $app->post('/testAjax', function () {
    return 'I am here';
 });
```

to

```
 $app->post('testAjax', function () {
    return 'I am here';
 });
```

Comment: I don't think the absolute path is the problem. I tested and your solution doesn't work